# 2 layer NN weights not updating

Tags: python-2.7, neural-network, tensorflow

I have a fairly simple NN that has 1 hidden layer.

However, the weights don't seem to be updating. Or perhaps they are but the variable values don't change ?

Either way, my accuracy is 0.1 and it doesn't change no matter I change the learning rate or the activation function. Not sure what is wrong. Any ideas ?

I've posted the entire code correctly formatter so you guys can directly copy paste it and run it on your local machines.

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import math
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# one hot option returns binarized labels. mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data/', one_hot=True)   
# model parameters 
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [784, None],name='x')
# weights 
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([25, 784],stddev= 1.0/math.sqrt(784)),name='W') 
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([25, 25],stddev=1.0/math.sqrt(25)),name='W')  
W3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([10, 25],stddev=1.0/math.sqrt(25)),name='W') 

# bias units b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([25,1]),name='b1') 
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([25,1]),name='b2') 
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10,1]),name='b3')

# NN architecture 
hidden1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(W1, x,name='hidden1')+b1, name='hidden1_out')

# hidden2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(W2, hidden1, name='hidden2')+b2, name='hidden2_out')

y = tf.matmul(W3, hidden1,name='y') + b3

y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [10, None],name='y_')

# Create the model   
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y, y_)) 
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(2).minimize(cross_entropy)  

sess = tf.Session()   
summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('log_simple_graph', sess.graph)   
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()   
sess.run(init)   
# Train 
for i in range(1000):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    summary =sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: np.transpose(batch_xs), y_: np.transpose(batch_ys)})
    if summary is not None:
        summary_writer.add_event(summary)

# Test trained model 
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1)) 
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: np.transpose(mnist.test.images),  y_: np.transpose(mnist.test.labels)}))
```

Comment: Can you please reformat the code so that it's clear what lines are comments? I notice that you're using a learning rate of 2 for the `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer`, which is very large. Does reducing it to 0.1 or 0.01 improve the accuracy?

Comment: sorry about that. Was fixing it when you noticed. It should be good now.

Comment: Nope. As I already mentioned that changing the learning rate or the activation function doesn't do anything. Accuracy goes to 0 for a learning rate of 0.01.

Comment: You can also see if the model is learning anything by printing loss value (cross_entryopy) and making sure it goes does while you train. Note as you use stochastic gradient descent, loss will not exactly go down at each step but the trend should be clear.

Comment: Thanks ! It seems like they are growing out of proportion ! Why is that ?
`64.3306
5137.85
472461.0
6.31276e+07
5.63593e+09
6.66432e+11
4.70562e+13
3.36811e+15
3.02287e+17
5.13433e+19
4.08305e+21
4.40701e+23
3.30391e+25
3.35825e+27
2.74717e+29
2.13102e+31
1.19033e+33
1.28649e+35
9.36408e+36
nan
nan
nan`

Comment: Did you try to reduce the learning rate?

Comment: yes. As I said before in my original post, it doesn't seem to effect the trend. If I make it 0.001, it stops diverging and just stays around 45.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting 0.1 accuracy consistently **is mainly due to the order of dimensions of the input placeholder and the weights following it**. Learning rate is another factor. If the learning rate is very high, the gradient would be oscillating and will not reach any minima.

Tensorflow takes the number of instances(batches) as the first index value of placeholder. So the code which declares input x

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [784, None],name='x')
```

should be declared as

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784],name='x')
```

Consequently, W1 should be declared as

```
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([784, 25],stddev= 1.0/math.sqrt(784)),name='W')
```

and so on.. Even the bias variables should be declared in the transpose sense. (Thats how tensorflow takes it :) )

For example

```
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([25]),name='b1') 
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([25]),name='b2') 
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]),name='b3')
```

I'm putting the corrected full code below for your reference. I achieved an accuracy of 0.9262 with this :D

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import math
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# one hot option returns binarized labels. 
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data/', one_hot=True)   
# model parameters 
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784],name='x')
# weights 
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([784, 25],stddev= 1.0/math.sqrt(784)),name='W') 
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([25, 25],stddev=1.0/math.sqrt(25)),name='W')  
W3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([25, 10],stddev=1.0/math.sqrt(25)),name='W') 

# bias units 
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([25]),name='b1') 
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([25]),name='b2') 
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]),name='b3')

# NN architecture 
hidden1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, W1,name='hidden1')+b1, name='hidden1_out')

# hidden2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(W2, hidden1, name='hidden2')+b2, name='hidden2_out')

y = tf.matmul(hidden1, W3,name='y') + b3

y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10],name='y_')

# Create the model   
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y, y_)) 
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(cross_entropy)  

sess = tf.Session()   
summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('log_simple_graph', sess.graph)   
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()   
sess.run(init)

for i in range(1000):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    summary =sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
    if summary is not None:
        summary_writer.add_event(summary)

# Test trained model 
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1)) 
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images,  y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

Comment: Great ! Where does it say that on TF documentation ?

Comment: [link]https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html

Comment: You can go to this line

Comment: "The first dimension is an index into the list of images and the second dimension is the index for each pixel in each image"

Comment: ok. But the official TF documentation does not state that for any optimization algorithm, the first dimension must be the number of instances. That is confusing. That line you pointed to is very specific to that example.